# Adding youtube link in html

Tags: html, youtube, embed

I tried adding this youtube link into my html code and everytime I try to play the video, it gives me a playback error. 
I was just wondering if I am missing any piece of code or if it just internet issues?
Thanks
The code is in the comments because for some reason it is not letting me attach my code in the body.

Comment: <iframe width="420" height="345" 
       src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/watch?v=TbDyiwurjwI"frameborder="0" allowfullscreen> </iframe>

Comment: "Whenever I try this code in html" What code?

Comment: @gingerCodeNinja I was unable to link it in the question, I have put it in the comments.. sorry for the misunderstanding!

Comment: @aCrainic you can press [edit] and update your question. Check the console of your browser "press F12 key > check (Console) tab" and see the errors you might have. Please [edit] your question with the detail of the error you have.

Comment: You don't "attach" code, you write it in the description. You can use the code "{}" button to style it as a code block.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to that actual video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TbDyiwurjwI

and then go to "Share" then "Embed" you'll see the embed code is

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TbDyiwurjwI" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

So the iframe URL is https://www.youtube.com/embed/TbDyiwurjwI not http://youtube.com/embed/watch?v=TbDyiwurjwI

I don't know where you got http://youtube.com/embed/watch?v=TbDyiwurjwI from, but you can't just construct URLs and hope they work, the server has to support them.